# Batch file: Save as in a batch file (.cmd)

Tags: windows, excel, batch-file, cmd

anyone who knows the command for save an excel file (xls) to txt (Tab delimited) in an batchfile ? I have a batch file that opens a sertain excel file and the only thing i want now is that the batch file (.cmd) shall save the file as txt.(Tab Delimited) and then Close the file, anyone knows the commands for this ?

Comment: i dont think there is a way using the excel.exe itself - you will need to write a macro that will save it as a csv. You can call the macro using  a vbs script  and call the vbs script by batch file passing the path of the xls file only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be appropriate command-line switches available, but here's some VBA code that might get you started.

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:="yourfilename", FileFormat:=xlCSV
```